# Impulse doesn't apply in Sprite Kit

Tags: sprite-kit, sprite, physics

I'm attempting to apply an impulse to a sprite node in SK every time I touch, but nothing is happening. The touch is registering, but there is no impulse.

```
-(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size {    
 if (self = [super initWithSize:size]) {
     /* Setup your scene here */

    self.backgroundColor = [SKColor colorWithRed:0.15 green:0.15 blue:0.3 alpha:1.0];
    self.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithEdgeLoopFromRect:self.frame];

    SKSpriteNode *torso = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[SKColor blueColor] size:CGSizeMake(40, 60)];
    torso.position = CGPointMake (250,250);
    torso.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:CGSizeMake(40, 60)];
    torso.physicsBody.dynamic = YES;

    [self addChild: torso];

    SKSpriteNode *arm = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[SKColor redColor] size:CGSizeMake(15, 50)];
    arm.position = CGPointMake (235,235);
    arm.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:CGSizeMake(40, 60)];
    arm.physicsBody.dynamic = YES;

    [self addChild: arm];

    SKPhysicsJointPin *leftArm = [SKPhysicsJointPin jointWithBodyA:torso.physicsBody bodyB:arm.physicsBody anchor:torso.position];
    [self.physicsWorld addJoint:leftArm];


   }
   return self;
}

-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{

    [_torso.physicsBody applyImpulse:CGVectorMake(12, 10)];
    NSLog(@"touch");
}
```

My sprite node does have another node linked to it, but I tried the impulse on it without the additional node and it still did not work.

Comment: You create a new instance of `torso` in `initWithSize:`, but you never seem to set `_torso` to anything.

Comment: @MikeS Unless I didn't fix it like I thought I did, a correction to the instance name didn't change anything!

Comment: What exactly did you change?

Comment: set a breakpoint and check if _torso is nil

Comment: @LearnCocos2D it was nil, I answered my question. Thanks both for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, in order to move my sprite node I had to create it like this

```
_torso = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[SKColor blueColor] size:CGSizeMake(40, 60)];
```

rather than

```
 SKSpriteNode *torso = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[SKColor blueColor] size:CGSizeMake(40, 60)];
```

Once I set a breakpoint and saw that _torso was nil, I referred to some previous work and saw my mistake.

Comment: did you declare torso as weak variable/property? That would explain it.